# Appcelerator Studio - Default Alloy Project does not work

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I have a problem with my Appcelerator Studio. When I create a new project from New -> Mobile App Project -> Default Alloy Project and run it (Mobile Web Preview in Browser) I get only this [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGZ8b.png):

Parameters: Windows 10, Titanium SDK: 5.2.2.GA, Appcelerator Studio 4.5.0

Project built successfully:

*[INFO] :   Project built successfully in 8s 532ms*

But in my log file I have:

```
   *!ENTRY com.appcelerator.titanium.core 4 0 2016-04-26 11:13:47.591
    !MESSAGE (Build 4.5.0.201602170821) [ERROR]  Location to be watched doesn't exist: C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32*

    *!ENTRY com.appcelerator.titanium.core 4 0 2016-04-26 11:13:47.593
    !MESSAGE (Build 4.5.0.201602170821) [ERROR]  Location to be watched doesn't exist: C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\modules*
```

When I changed version of Titanium SDK to 5.4.0 in tiapp.xml then project built successful and log file was clear but I have still only a red page (from image).

However when I imported the sample project (Employee Directory) and run, then  it works fine.

Did anyone have the same problem?

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug. Thanks for that! Could you check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, please create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.